# How to align 3 equations at 2 places, where the last 2 equations have one vertically centred label?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignment

I want something like the image in the picture shown: three equations aligned at the limiting sign, but with the final two equations having one vertically aligned label.

[image]

I have tried using `aligned` inside an `align` environment, but it makes the first equation right-aligned (thus ruining the alignment at the limiting sign). Does anyone know how to fix this right-align? See below:

[image]

This is the code which I used:

```
\begin{align}
    \hat\gamma^\lambda &\rightharpoonup \gamma \text{ weakly in } X_{x}(....), \label{A} \\
    \begin{aligned}\label{B}
        \hat\gamma^\lambda(0, \cdot) &\rightharpoonup \gamma(0, \cdot) \text{ weakly in } X_{x}(....),\\
        \hat\gamma^\lambda(1, \cdot) &\rightharpoonup \gamma(1, \cdot) \text{ weakly in } X_{x}(....).
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the few cases (IMO) where one should use `split` instead of `aligned` (note that split only supports one `&` per row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \hat\gamma^\lambda &\rightharpoonup \gamma \text{ weakly in } X_{x}(....), \label{A} \\
    \begin{split}\label{B}
        \hat\gamma^\lambda(0, \cdot) &\rightharpoonup \gamma(0, \cdot) \text{ weakly in } X_{x}(....),\\
        \hat\gamma^\lambda(1, \cdot) &\rightharpoonup \gamma(1, \cdot) \text{ weakly in } X_{x}(....).
    \end{split}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For some reason, split environment will not produce the shared equation label. I'll play around with it. Thanks!

Comment: @tashakinns as can be seen from the image is does for me. Please add an example to your querstion where my solutiuon does not produce a label (look out for left over `\nonumber` or `\notag`)